# how to display fetch data by an API request in angular as an observable?

Tags: angular, api, observable

Hello please I'm new to angular and I'm facing a problem: I'm trying to retrieve data given to me by an API. These data are in the form of observables and my application is lazy-loader and uses a resolver.

data is showing in browser console post request in network tab now i am trying to fetch this data to show as observables by doing an injection with input but i am getting the following error: "ERROR Type error: ctx.site is not defined"

what to do please?

here is how I subscribe to this observable: I subscribe in site-liste.component.ts then I inject the site property via an input to a site-liste-item.component.ts then I display in site-liste-item. component and I make a <app-site-list-item *ngFor="let site of site$ | async" [site]="site" >  in site-listecomponent.html for display my array of observable code from site-liste.component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, map } from 'rxjs';
import {Site} from 'src/app/core/models/site';
import { HomeService } from '../../services/home.services';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Making up
({
  selector: 'app-site-list',
  templateUrl: './site-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./site-list.component.scss']
})
export class SiteListComponent
{
  website$! : Observable<Site[]>
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute){}

ngOnInit()
{
  this.site$ = this.route.data.pipe(map(data => data['site'] ));
}

  
}

site-list-item.component.ts code
```